# How to remove all non numeric characters between brackets/parentheses with a regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove all non numeric characters between brackets and parentheses from a string, e.g `"hello (a1b2c3) (abc)"` would become `"hello 123"`.

How would I do it using a regex?

Comment: @TheLostMind im using this in a bigger project with a more complicated regex, which removes more characters than that and didn't think that would be relevant to this question, this is the regex which will eventually contain the stuff from above aswell: "((?s)(<|\\[|\").*?(>|\\]|\\}))|\\(|\\)"

Comment: I think you might need a parser here.  My original (wrong) answer was given at a glance and assumed you just wanted to completely remove the bracketed terms.

Comment: Are there unbalanced or escaped parentheses as well?

Comment: @anubhava there aren't

Comment: You should edit your current code into the question body, not just post it in the comment. It's the primary cause of those down votes.

Comment: Is there any closing brackets( `) ` ) between the brackets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per comment from OP there are no unbalanced or escaped quotes. Keeping that in mind here is a single `replaceAll` method call to achieve that:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("(?:\\D(?=[^(]*\\))|\\)\\s*)", "");

//=> hello 123
```

Using a positive lookahead we are finding all non-digits that are inside the parenthesis using lookahead `\\D(?=[^(]*\\))` and then we remove `)` followed by optional spaces in an alternation.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBka56/12)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` and `replaceAll` to achieve this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hel121lo (a1b2c3) (abc)";
    String[] arr = s.split("\\s+");
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
    for (String str : arr) {
        // System.out.println(str);
        if (str.contains("(")) {
            String k = str.replaceAll("\\D|\\(|\\)a", "");
            sj.add(k);
        } else {
            sj.add(str);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(sj.toString());

}
```

O/P :

```
hel121lo 123
```